# Right click graphics problem Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, gui

[image: Strange graphics surrounding click]

Strange graphics surrounding right click anywhere i click in the gui. This problem goes off when i log out and back in! But every alternate time this happens, only solution being i log out back and in!

This is very strange problem, help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just install a newer Nvidia driver.

Comment: how can this happpen only on right click?

Comment: this is latest driver as well, 375.66